# How to make Rails react to urls like http://username:password@localhost/foo/bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Zencoder to trancode our media and reading about [notifications](https://app.zencoder.com/docs/guides/getting-started/notifications). In the [article](https://app.zencoder.com/docs/guides/getting-started/notifications), there's a block of code that looks like:

```
  "notifications": [
    {"format": "xml", "url": "http://user:password@example.com/zencoder1"},
    {"format": "json", "url": "http://user:password@example.com/zencoder2"},
    "http://example.com/zencoder3",
    "admin@example.com"
  ]
```

Which basically tells Zencoder to send notifications via url and/or email. If Zencoder sends a notification to:

```
 {"format": "xml", "url": "http://username:password@localhost:3000/zencoder/notification"}
```

How can I make my Zencoder controller, notification action react to user:password? If I browse to "http://username:password@localhost:3000/zencoder/notification" Firefox throws a message:

> **Confirm**
>
> You are about to log in to the site
>   "localhost" with the username "username", but
>   the website does not require
>   authentication. This may be an attempt
>   to trick you.
>
> Is "localhost" the site you want to
>   visit?

Ideally, in Zencoder#notification, I would like to parse through username and password. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It's just basic HTTP Basic Auth. Solution can be viewed [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication) and [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html).